# What intelligence was released in order to "blunt Chinese saber-rattling in the Taiwan Strait"?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, china, taiwan, intelligence

From Time Magazine's March X, 2024 [Inside the White House Program to Share America’s Secrets](https://time.com/6835724/americas-intelligence-secrets/):

> The motivation behind the program, the officials say, is that it works. Strategic declassification has denied Russian President Vladimir Putin “false narratives,” Burns said in a speech last summer, “putting him in the uncomfortable and unaccustomed position of being on his back foot.” The effort has expanded beyond Russia. **The U.S. has declassified intelligence to blunt Chinese saber-rattling in the Taiwan Strait**, to pressure Iran to stop supplying weapons to the Houthis attacking shipping vessels in the Red Sea, and to counter Hamas’ false claims about Israeli strikes. “This is a game changer,” says Kirby. “I hope they never put it back in the bottle.”

**Question:** What intelligence was released in order to "blunt Chinese saber-rattling in the Taiwan Strait"?

Let's not litigate how one measures the degree to which saber-rattling can be "blunted", but instead focus on what bits of intelligence were released with that goal in mind.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to me that's explained in the article you linked (i.e. what they mean by that)

> Ahead of then House Speaker Nancy Pelosi’s visit to Taiwan in August 2022, Kirby briefed a declassified intelligence-community analysis of the steps China might take in response, including military provocations like firing missiles in the Taiwan Strait. The goal was to diminish the shock value of any retaliation by Beijing for Pelosi’s trip, a senior White House official says.